# jQuery each click change background

Tags: jquery, background

I have a question about jQuery animation. Each click should change the background image.

This is my example, it doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/kRjrn/215/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    function deneme(){
    $('#background').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000);
    }
    function deneme2(){
    $('#background2').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000);
    }

    $("#deneme").click(deneme);
    $("#deneme2").click(deneme2);

});
```

How do I get it to work?

Comment: Part of your issue might be that `#background2` doesn't exist...

Comment: The first link works in Chrome, the second is not assigned, you'll have to add `$("#deneme2").click(deneme2);` Also change "background2" to just "background" as suggested

Comment: in css there is already a #background2

Comment: @aldimeola1122  and in html?!

Comment: When you edit your original question it's better to put changes in an EDIT at the bottom.  Otherwise you just confuse everyone.

Comment: I think you should work with classes in your CSS and animate between them or something around. Seems like use want to use CSS ids to set the background. Maybe you should directly what are your root needs

Comment: By the way there are the fadeOut()/fadeIn() methods

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/hWgZ8/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function deneme(){
    $('#background2').animate({ opacity: 0,queue:false }, 3000);
    $('#background').animate({ opacity: 1 ,queue:false}, 3000);
}
function deneme2(){
    $('#background').animate({ opacity: 0 ,queue:false}, 3000);
    $('#background2').animate({ opacity: 1 ,queue:false}, 3000);
}

$("#deneme").click(deneme);
$("#deneme2").click(deneme2);
```

});

Edit: the "queue: false" is so that it doesn't wait for the previous animation

Comment: +1 for queuing; that usually throws beginners in jquery animations for a loop!

Comment: aha, i didn't do the queueing thing in my answer.  That's much tidier than putting it in a function callback :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a few things, you didn't have the div #background2, and also you didn't set up your click handler (in the jsFiddle demo you provided)

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kRjrn/220)

```
function deneme () {
    $('#background2').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 100);
    $('#background').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000);
}
function deneme2 () {
    $('#background').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 100);
    $('#background2').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000);
}

$("#deneme").click(deneme);
$("#deneme2").click(deneme2);
```

Comment: and maybe hide previous background for each click

Comment: thanks that was good, but if i click 1.Sayfa and than 2.Sayfa comes nothing

Answer (score 1):

I took a different approach using `data-attributes` to simplify the code and make it a bit more reusable. http://jsfiddle.net/kRjrn/222/

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you didn't have the `#background2` DOM element or the handler for that element set. Also, the backgrounds will overlay each other if you are clicking between them without them switching position. That is, the second background will cover the first. Unless you hide the opposite background in the event handlers for each.

Like so (http://jsfiddle.net/kRjrn/221/):

```
function deneme(){
    $('#background').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000);
    $('#background2').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000);
}
function deneme2(){
    $('#background2').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000); 
    $('#background').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what you actually want to happen, but if the desired result is that when you click either link it changes the background image, with a fade-in-fade-out transition, i think it would be better done by changing the class of the background.    I would do it as in this forked fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4JGmK/1/

changed css:

```
#background {
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.background1 {
    background-image: url("http://www.noupe.com/wp-content/themes/noupe/images/noupe-404.png");
}
.background2 {
    background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7b/Sdf_losc-benf_22.11.05_-_4.JPG");
}
```

changed js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#deneme").click(function(){deneme('background1', 'background2')});
    $("#deneme2").click(function(){deneme('background2', 'background1')});
});

function deneme(newclass, oldclass) {
    if ($('#background').hasClass(oldclass)) {
        //fade out the other background first then fade the right one in
        $('#background').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 3000, function () {
            $('#background').removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 3000);
        });
    } else if($('#background').hasClass(newclass)) {
        //already got this background, don't do anything
        return false;
    } else {
        //doesn't have either at the moment, fade in the right background
        $('#background').addClass(newclass).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

The deneme function i refactored still feels a bit clunky but it works at least.